# Sed expression for IP address, getting unexpected result for matching group

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to extract an IP address from a text, and don't understand the outcome according to the regex I write. Apparantly this:

```
echo '"IPAddress": "173.14.0.3",' | sed -n -r -e 's/"IPAddress": "(.*)"/\1/p'
```

returns

```
173.14.0.3,
```

Why do I get the `,`at the end? Doesn't `"(.*)"` instruct the regex to create a matching group of everything between the last two `"`?

Originally I started out with

```
echo '"IPAddress": "173.14.0.3",' | sed -n -r -e 's/"IPAddress": "([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3})"/\1/p'
```

, but got same result. I used [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Fy5Lj3/3), and there I get a different response. Why?

Comment: regex101 doesn't support sed's regular expressions. You can't use it for sed.

Comment: Is the input a json document?

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes, but I'm more interested in how sed works. I know there are better ways to parse json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input:

```
input:            "IPAddress": "173.14.0.3",
matched by regex: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  (note: comma not matched)
captured:                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The matched part is replaced by the captured substring and substituted back into the original string, yielding:

```
result:       173.14.0.3,
not affected:           ^
replacement:  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you want to get rid of the comma, include it in the match (so it gets substituted by nothing):

```
s/"IPAddress": "(.*)",/\1/p
```

regex101 shows the same behavior: https://regex101.com/r/Fy5Lj3/4

Comment: Even if it looks the same in this case, regex101 doesn't support posix regular expression and can't be used as a reference

Comment: @hek2mgl Not in general, right. But in this case it's just `.*` and the behavior is the same.

Comment: That's still *very* misleading if you give that to a beginner. You should have explained that as you see that the OP doesn't know that.

Comment: @hek2mgl Why do you think OP doesn't know that?

Comment: Because they say that they've used regex101 to test the sed command: `but got same result. I used regex101, and there I get a different response. Why?`

Comment: @hek2mgl That's just a misunderstanding: The regex itself behaves identically; they just weren't looking at substitution results, only at matched substrings. My link demonstrates the "SUBSTITUTION" feature of regex101 and that the result is in fact the same.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. I thought the /p with the -n option makes sed omit what is not matched. So when I didn't specify to match `,`, it wouldn't be output either?

Comment: @erihanse From [the sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html): "the `s` command attempts to match the pattern space against the supplied regular expression *regexp*; if the match is successful, then that portion of the pattern space which was matched is replaced with *replacement*." ... "**`p`**  If the substitution was made, then print the new pattern space." I.e. it prints the whole resulting pattern space, not just *replacement*.

Comment: I think I understand my misconception now. I thought it would replace only the matching, but it takes the whole input, replaces the pattern with the substitution, and also keeps whatever was not matched. If I match the comma as well, that part will also be substituted. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

General advice: regex101.com does **not** support the regular expression languages supported by `sed`. These are explained in the [`POSIX`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html) specification.

While simple things *might* look similar, expressions **differ significantly** in detail. Do **not** use regex101 when working on regular expressions for `sed`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15257373)

Comment: I disagree with that in this special case.

Comment: The question being asked is _"Why do I get the ,at the end?"_ The use of regex101.com is tangential to the question, so your 'answer' should have been a comment.

Comment: The OP, as they stated are just in the process of learning sed - using regex101. That's why it is a pretty good advice - imo. The answer to the specific problem asked in this question would be to use `jq` since it is json. (as confirmed by the OP). So it leaves the question, "help me with my first steps in sed". I think my answer makes perfectly sense, and was just given in the hope to be helpful to the OP. Believe me, a lot of questions pop up because people don't realize that regex engines differ and sed does not understand the same syntax as perl or php.